# How to display the value instead of the ID in the form in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I need to display the time, but the form outputs the ID

models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    concert = models.ForeignKey('Concert', related_name='concert_name', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_time = models.ForeignKey('Time', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f"{self.first_name}, {self.last_name}, {self.date_time}"
    
class Concert(models.Model):
    name_concert = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    length = models.TimeField()
    type = models.ForeignKey('Type', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    janr = models.ForeignKey('Janr', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    regisser = models.ForeignKey('Regisser', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date_time = models.ForeignKey('Time', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='photo/', blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name_concert
    
class Time(models.Model):
        date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return format(self.date_time, "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")
```

forms.py

```
class ticketForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Ticket
            fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'concert', 'date_time', 'price', 'place']
    
            widgets = {
                "first_name": TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'input-style',
                    'placeholder': 'Имя'
                }),
                "last_name": TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'input-style',
                    'placeholder': 'Фамилия'
                }),
                "concert": TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'input-style',
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'value': 'ticket.concert_name',
                    'readonly': 'readonly'
                }),
                "date_time": TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'input-style',
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'value': 'ticket.date_time',
                    'readonly': 'readonly'
                }),
                "price": TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'input-style',
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'value': 'ticket.price',
                    'readonly': 'readonly'
                }),
                "place": TextInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'input-style',
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'value': '',
                    'readonly': 'readonly'
                })
        }
```

views.py

```
    def ticketsSite(request, concert_id):
        ticket = get_object_or_404(Concert, id=concert_id)
    
        form = ticketForm(initial={'concert': ticket.name_concert,
                                   'price': ticket.price,
                                   'date_time': ticket.date_time})
    
        context = {
            'ticket': ticket,
            'form': form
        }
    
        return render(request, 'main/ticketsSite.html', context=context)
```

I am specifically interested in the line `'value': 'ticket.date_time'` in file **forms.py**.
If you output: `{{ticket.date_time }}`, then it outputs in the desired format, when as in: `{{form.date_time }}` - **value** takes the ID value.

How do I make value take a value in the desired date format?

I tried to find a solution on the internet, but I couldn't find it. Or I found it, but because of the small amount of knowledge, I did not understand the solution.
I have absolutely no idea how to convert this, I hope for your help.

Comment: Why not have your date input be a `SelectDateWidget` instead of a `TextInput`?